# Disappear grails alert message after 10 second

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am working on a database website and came across this problem. Currently I have a function that display message when user successfully create a customer.

```
<div class = "col-md-6">
   <g:if test="${flash.message}">
      <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}!</div>
   </g:if>                       
</div>
```

But I want this message to disappear after 10 seconds. Any ideas how can I achieve this?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#successMessage').fadeOut('fast');
}, 10000);
```

This will fade away your div(popup) after 10 seconds